# Regular Expression Help... apostrophes within words

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match the first 8 words of a string (including any punctuation at the end), but I'm running into problems when a word contains an apostrophe or single quote character. My current regex is as follow:

```
/(\b[\w,']+[.?'!\"]*\s){8}/
```

and my example string is:

```
Went for Valentine's day, food was about a B, filet mignon was served chopped up
```

Currently, The match i'm getting returned is this:

```
s day, food was about a B, filet
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
Went for Valentine's day, food was about a
```

I tried introudcing a `'` into my character set `[\w,']` but it's not working correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to get everything coming before the 8th space?

Comment: You should escape the dot inside your regex.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Why yes, it would! I never though about it that way! What would that regex look like?

Comment: Why not just [split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) the string on `\s+` and take the first eight elements of the resulting array?

Comment: If you mean how to escape, you should write \. instead of .

Comment: @JackManey Thanks! that's so much easier. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa actually you don't need to escape the dot in this case, it's inside a character class. But it wont harm as the escape character will be omitted when interpreted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this can be done with a regex, this can be done with [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) at least as easily:

```
$string="Went for Valentine's day, food was about a B, filet mignon was served chopped up";

$words=preg_split("/\s+/",$string);

#If there are more than eight words, only take the first eight elements of $words.
if(count($words)>8)
{
  $words=array_slice($words,0,8);
}

echo implode(" ",$words) . "\n";
```

This produces the following output:

```
Went for Valentine's day, food was about a
```

Answer (score 1):

This essentially counts apostrophes as word characters:

```
\b(\w|')+\b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include apostrophe in a regular expression the right way to go is doing something like this.

```
[\w']+
```

Then you can have the word boundary as needed. `\b`

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "Knock, knock. Who's there? r2d2!";
$pattern = "/(?:\w'\w|\w)+/";
$words = preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```